# Parsing ISO-8859-1 w/ NSXmlParser

Tags: xml, iphone, character-encoding, nsxmlparser

I am usin the nsxmlparser and am wondering how I can parse ISO-8859-1 correctly into an NSString.

Currently, I am getting results w/ Â for two-byte characters.

The XML I'm using (not created by me) starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

Here are the basic calls I'm using (omitted the NSThread calls).

```
NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sampleFileName ofType:@"xml"];

NSString *xmlFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSData *data = [xmlFileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

[parser setDelegate:self];

[parser parse];
```

Comment: It does look like your source encoding may be at least partially UTF-8.  I recommend posting a sample (or a link to a sample) so it can be further diagnosed.

Comment: I see at the top the line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>. I assume that's the encoding? How do I set NSXmlParser to use that?

Comment: Travis: That's the prolog containing the encoding declaration, yes. It might be wrong! Or the parser might not be using it correctly. Either way, no, you should not need to tell the parser; it should be obeying the declaration as is (if it recognises the name of the encoding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) **recommends an explicit [character encoding declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-EncodingDecl)** in the document prolog. Your input document likely has one; that will tell you the encoding that the parser must use to interpret the character input.

In the absence of an explicit declaration, the same section says to **treat the input as UTF-8 or UTF-16** (and the document is in error if it turns out not to be encoded as either of those).

So, if your XML parser is either ignoring the explicit encoding declaration, or using the wrong encoding if there's no explicit declaration, your parser is Doing It Wrong™ and needs to be fixed to conform to the XML specification.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense. Sorry I'm a bit new at this. So at the top of my XML document is the line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>. That's the encoding right? So I have to tell NSXmlParser this?

Comment: Note that the XML spec doesn't require the parser to understand anything other than UTF-8 and UTF-16 (section 2.2). I have never used the XML parser in question, so I don't know for sure, but it could be the case that NSXmlParser doesn't support anything beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your header thinks it's ISO-8859-1 and from the behavior (ending up with two characters instead of one) it sounds like at least some of your content is already UTF-8.  This looks like a classic "double utf-8 encoding issue" where content already encoded as UTF-8 is encoded again as UTF-8.  Change the header to say UTF-8 and it just might start working.  You could try always running your code through as UTF-8 and then as what it says it is (since if it's not UTF-8 you'll get a parser error).

Finally note that the encoding of an XML file is overridden by the HTTP header if it's served over HTTP.

Not sure if it applies to your need, but I love this article on [parsing XML at all costs](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/2003/01/22/dive-into-xml.html).  As an example, I'll point out that I also love [feedparser](http://feedparser.org) (Python) as its the best XML at-all-costs XML parser (great for ideas but not your situation).

Comment: Great info thank you. So if I have an http link to an XML file what is the easy way to get that file downloaded locally for me to look at without HTTP modifying it? I tried in Safari but haven't found it yet.

Comment: For debugging purposes I tend to use either `curl` or `wget` on the command line and tell them to show me the headers.  In a browser I'll use Firefox along with an extension like FireBug to show the headers.  For viewing the content in the browser I just right click on it and select "View Source".